# What is the reason for this behavior of Keras Normalizer layer with 1D features?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When I execute the following Keras code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

n_input = 100
n_entries = 10
n_features = 2

features = np.random.random(n_entries*n_input*n_features)
features = features.reshape((n_entries, n_input, n_features))

model = keras.Sequential()
norm = layers.Normalization(-1)
norm.adapt(features)
model.add(norm)
print(norm.output)
```

I get `<KerasTensor: shape=(None, None, 2) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'normalization_28')>` with 2D output shape as expected.

However, changing `n_features` to 1:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

n_input = 100
n_entries = 10
n_features = 1

features = np.random.random(n_entries*n_input*n_features)
features = features.reshape((n_entries, n_input, n_features))

model = keras.Sequential()
norm = layers.Normalization(-1)
norm.adapt(features)
model.add(norm)
print(norm.output)
```

I get `<KerasTensor: shape=(None, None, None) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'normalization_29')>`, with `None` shape, where I would expect 1.

This breaks the pipeline, making 1D features an exceptional case.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the way the input shape is inferred and the way the output shape is computed. However, I looked at the source code and could not find anything unusual. As a workaround, you can explicitly define the `input_shape` so it will not be inferred:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

n_input = 100
n_entries = 10
n_features = 1

features = np.random.random(n_entries*n_input*n_features)
features = features.reshape((n_entries, n_input, n_features))

model = keras.Sequential()
norm = layers.Normalization(-1, input_shape=(None, n_features))
norm.adapt(features)
model.add(norm)
print(norm.output)
```

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='normalization_33/truediv:0', description="created by layer 'normalization_33'")
```

Comment: It's definitely a useful comment, thanks! However, I think it doesn't answer the "why" of my question, that's the reason I didn't mark it as accepted.

Comment: It’s probably because the shape (10,100,1) is equivalent to (10,100)